# How to reuse code (a Guard) defined in a submachine in the parent SM (using boost-msm)?

Tags: boost, template-meta-programming, state-machine, boost-msm

I've defined a guard in a sub-state machine and now I want to use the exact logic/guard in the parent SM (using boost-msm). using the same guard in the transition_table results in compilation error: unknown type name 'GuardSS'.

I've defined the guard (and its corresponding value) in the sub-machine, but it can be moved to the parent SM if it helps in solving the problem and allows me to  reuse the guard.

A sample code can be found [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/6IdQv61dv05Ghjig).

How can I reuse the code used in the guard?

> Code included:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "myfsm.h"

int main()
{    
    std::cout << "Testing boost::msm ..." << std::endl;
    MyFsm fsm;
    fsm.start();

    fsm.process_event(Event12());

    fsm.process_event(Event_ss12());

    //guard valu changes
    MyFsm_::State2 &state = fsm.get_state<MyFsm_::State2&>();
    state.m_guardVal = true;

    fsm.process_event(Event_ss12());

    fsm.process_event(Event21());//?protect this transition using the same Guard
}
```

fsm.h:

```
#ifndef MYFSM
#define MYFSM

#include <iostream>
#include <boost/msm/back/state_machine.hpp>
#include <boost/msm/front/state_machine_def.hpp>
#include <boost/msm/front/functor_row.hpp>

struct Event12{};
struct Event21{};
struct Event_ss12{};
struct Event_ss21{};

namespace msm = boost::msm;
namespace msmf = boost::msm::front;
namespace mpl = boost::mpl;

struct MyFsm_ : msmf::state_machine_def<MyFsm_>
{
    struct State1 : msmf::state<>{
        template<class Event, class Fsm> void on_entry(const Event&, Fsm&) const {std::cout << "State1::on_entry()" << std::endl;}
        template<class Event, class Fsm> void on_exit(const Event&, Fsm&) const {std::cout << "State1::on_exit()" << std::endl;}
    };    

    struct State2_ : msmf::state_machine_def<State2_>{
        template <class Event,class Fsm> void on_entry(Event const&, Fsm&) const {std::cout << "State2::on_entry()" << std::endl;}
        template <class Event,class Fsm> void on_exit(Event const&, Fsm&) const {std::cout << "State1::on_exit()" << std::endl;}

        struct SubState1 : msmf::state<> {
            template <class Event,class Fsm> void on_entry(Event const&, Fsm&) const {std::cout << "SubState1::on_entry()" << std::endl;}
            template <class Event,class Fsm> void on_exit(Event const&, Fsm&) const {std::cout << "SubState1::on_exit()" << std::endl;}
            };
        struct SubState2 : msmf::state<> {
            template <class Event,class Fsm> void on_entry(Event const&, Fsm&) const {std::cout << "SubState2::on_entry()" << std::endl;}
            template <class Event,class Fsm> void on_exit(Event const&, Fsm&) const {std::cout << "SubState2::on_exit()" << std::endl;}
        };
        // Guards
        struct GuardSS {
            template <class Event, class Fsm, class SourceState, class TargetState>
            bool operator()(Event const&, Fsm& fsm, SourceState&, TargetState&) 
            {
                if (fsm.m_guardVal == true){
                    std::cout << "Transition Approved by Guard \n";
                    return true;
                }
                std::cout << "Transition Rejected by Guard \n";
                return false;
            }
        };
        typedef SubState1 initial_state;

        struct transition_table:mpl::vector<
                //          Start       Event       Next        Action      Guard
                msmf::Row < SubState1, Event_ss12, SubState2, msmf::none, GuardSS >,
                msmf::Row < SubState2, Event_ss21, SubState1, msmf::none, msmf::none >
                > {};

        bool m_guardVal=false;
    }; 
    typedef msm::back::state_machine<State2_> State2; 

   // Set initial state
   typedef State1 initial_state;

    // Transition table
    struct transition_table:mpl::vector<
         msmf::Row < State1, Event12, State2, msmf::none, msmf::none >,
         msmf::Row < State2, Event21, State1, msmf::none, GuardSS/*msmf::none*/ >         
    >{};

   template<class Event, class Fsm>
   void no_transition(Event const&, Fsm&, int state){
       std::cout<<"no_transiton detected from state: "<< state << std::endl;
   }

};
// Pick a back-end
typedef msm::back::state_machine<MyFsm_> MyFsm;


#endif // MYFSM
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the guard `GuardSS` to the parent state `MyFsm_`. Because `MyFsm_` cannot access to `GuardSS` in the original code.

In addition, you need to define a member variable `bool m_guardVal=false;` in `MyFsm_`. Because it is referred by `GuardSS`.

Here is updated code:

```
struct MyFsm_ : msmf::state_machine_def<MyFsm_>
{
    // Guards (moved to parent from sub)
    struct GuardSS {
        template <class Event, class Fsm, class SourceState, class TargetState>
        bool operator()(Event const&, Fsm& fsm, SourceState&, TargetState&) 
        {
            if (fsm.m_guardVal == true){
                std::cout << "Transition Approved by Guard \n";
                return true;
            }
            std::cout << "Transition Rejected by Guard \n";
            return false;
        }
    };

    bool m_guardVal=false; // added

    struct State1 : msmf::state<>{
    // ... snip ...
```

Running demo is https://wandbox.org/permlink/V4UJJo3csX427rYi